# How to Increase the numurical value of 3rd column in a particular row when some one click on the link which is in the 2nd column of same row

Tags: javascript, firebase

How to increase the numerical value of 3rd column in a particular row when some one click on the link which is in the 2nd column of same row? Data loads from firebase in tabular form.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AndroidAppania/286bf/16/), so you can understand it much better.

The script which loads (callback) data from firebase is given bellow

```
    var LEADERBOARD_SIZE = 10;
    var get_title = $('title').html();
    var get_id = $('id').find('textarea').html();

    // Create our Firebase reference
    var scoreListRef = new Firebase('https://androidappania.firebaseio.com//AlternateLinksDirectory//' + get_id);

    // Keep a mapping of firebase locations to HTML elements, so we can move / remove elements as necessary.
    var htmlForPath = {};

    // Helper function that takes a new score snapshot and adds an appropriate row to our leaderboard table.
    function handleScoreAdded(scoreSnapshot, prevScoreName) {
        var newScoreRow = $("");
        newScoreRow.append($("").append($("").text(scoreSnapshot.val().name)));
        newScoreRow.append($("").text(scoreSnapshot.val().url));
        newScoreRow.append($("").text(scoreSnapshot.val().score));

        // Store a reference to the table row so we can get it again later.
        htmlForPath[scoreSnapshot.name()] = newScoreRow;

        // Insert the new score in the appropriate place in the table.
        if (prevScoreName === null) {
            $("#leaderboardTable").append(newScoreRow);
        } else {
            var lowerScoreRow = htmlForPath[prevScoreName];
            lowerScoreRow.before(newScoreRow);
        }
    }

    // Helper function to handle a score object being removed; just removes the corresponding table row.
    function handleScoreRemoved(scoreSnapshot) {
        var removedScoreRow = htmlForPath[scoreSnapshot.name()];
        removedScoreRow.remove();
        delete htmlForPath[scoreSnapshot.name()];
    }

    // Create a view to only receive callbacks for the last LEADERBOARD_SIZE scores
    var scoreListView = scoreListRef.limit(LEADERBOARD_SIZE);

    // Add a callback to handle when a new score is added.
    scoreListView.on('child_added', function (newScoreSnapshot, prevScoreName) {
        handleScoreAdded(newScoreSnapshot, prevScoreName);
    });

    // Add a callback to handle when a score is removed
    scoreListView.on('child_removed', function (oldScoreSnapshot) {
        handleScoreRemoved(oldScoreSnapshot);
    });

    // Add a callback to handle when a score changes or moves positions.
    var changedCallback = function (scoreSnapshot, prevScoreName) {
        handleScoreRemoved(scoreSnapshot);
        handleScoreAdded(scoreSnapshot, prevScoreName);
    };
    scoreListView.on('child_moved', changedCallback);
    scoreListView.on('child_changed', changedCallback);

    // When the user presses enter on scoreInput, add the score, and update the highest score.
    $("#scoreInput").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var newScore = ($("#scoreInput").val());
            var url1 = $("#urlInput").val();
            var name = $("#nameInput").val();
            $("#scoreInput").val("");

            if (url1.length === 0)
                if (name.length === 0) return;

            var userScoreRef = scoreListRef.child(name);

            // Use setWithPriority to put the name / score in Firebase, and set the priority to be the score.
            userScoreRef.setWithPriority({
                name: name,
                url: url1,
                score: newScore
            }, newScore);

            alert('Alternate Link for this App has been Succesfully submitted by you. By using this service you agree that you will Not Spam or Submit Links which refers to illegal or Copyrighted content.');

        }
    });

    // delay function to make link clickable after 4 sec and also add onclick='HitCounter()' into links
    var delay = 4000 //4 seconds
    setTimeout(function () {

function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
        var re = /(\(.*?)?\b((?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_()|])/ig;
        return text.replace(re, function (match, lParens, url) {
            var rParens = '';
            lParens = lParens || '';
            var lParenCounter = /\(/g;
            while (lParenCounter.exec(lParens)) {
                var m;
                if (m = /(.*)(\.\).*)/.exec(url) || /(.*)(\).*)/.exec(url)) {
                    url = m[1];
                    rParens = m[2] + rParens;
                }
            }
            return lParens + "" + url + "" + rParens;
        });
    }
        var elm = document.getElementById('leaderboardTable');
        elm.innerHTML = replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(elm.innerHTML);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[href^='http://']").filter(function () {
            return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
        }).attr('target', '_blank');
    });

}, delay)
```

and the script which take care of URL Hit Counts is given bellow

```
function HitCounter() {
    var get_id = $('id').find('textarea').html();

    var HitCounterRef = new Firebase('https://androidappania.firebaseio.com//AlternateLinksDirectory//' + get_id);

    var hits = $(tbody).find('tr').children('td').html();

    if (hits == null) {
        hits = 1;
    } else {
        hits++;
    }

    HitCounterRef.setWithPriority({
        score: hits
    }, hits);
};
```

I need some modification or improvement in this code so that when some one click on a link then correct corresponding 3rd column of same row should get a increment/increase in it's numerical value.

I also need something which could create connection b/w HitCounter and urls given in 2nd column of every row or initiate the HitCounter function when some one click on any of the link given in 2nd column of every row.

Comment: @JeffO Now I have done some modification in javascript at the end so as to make links clickable.
Links are loaded in 2nd column (under "Alternate Download Link" heading).

Comment: Rather than giving us (apparently) the entirety of your code base, could you reduce this to a minimal/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) example of the code you're working with, so that we might be able to *easily* help? Also, explicitly telling your users that you don't/won't/can't check their submitted links more or less guarantees that your site will end up hosting links to various websites on the internet that you, the Police or the security services of your country would rather it did not. (I don't honestly think there's a fix for that, but it seemed worth mentioning.)

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you for your suggestions.
I will change that alert text to "Alternate Link for this App has been Succesfully submitted by you. By using this service you agree that you will Not Spam or Submit Links which refers to illegal or Copyrighted content."